# FindWindow() by incomplete name

Tags: c++, winapi, findwindow

Is there any way to find a window by an incomplete name?

For instance, how would you find a Google Chrome window which can have many title names?
like *Stack Overflow - Google Chrome*

FindWindow function would work great if the window would always have the same name as a function like the one below would solve it.

```
HWND chrome = FindWindow(NULL,_T("Stack Overflow - Google Chrome"));
SetForegroundWindow(chrome);
```

But, what happens if the name changes constantly (like browsers)? How can I find a window by searching for a fixed starting / ending?

I am looking for is something like `FindWindow(NULL,_T("something here - Google Chrome")`. 
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Use FindWindowEx and search by class

Comment: Are you still supporting Win98?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the window classname instead of the window title. For instance, you can find Firefox with

```
HWND firefox = FindWindow(_T("MozillaWindowClass"), NULL);
```

You can use any window spy type application like WinSight, WinSpy++, or (the one I used to find the Firefox window class) AutoHotkey's Window Spy utility.

For more info, see the MSDN documentation for [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: +1.  But if you need even tighter control (e.g. due to false positives from other apps, or if the class name isn't always consistent (unlikely)), then you can instead use [`EnumWindows()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and manually search for the desired window.